# Can't pass variables between two python files

Tags: python, variables

I have 2 python files. One is  speech.py and other is weather.py
What I want to do is, type a question (*i.e How is weather in New York*) and then pass the city name to weather.py file. Which would find the weather for that city and return the result back to speech.py and result will be printed by speech.py (*which is kind of my main file*). Both files give error saying that the other file has no attribute named forecast and city_to_find respectively. But I can clearly see the variables in both files.

**speech.py**

```
from weather import forecast
    if i['tag'] == 'weather':
    sentence = 'How is weather in New York'
    print('Okay, Let me search for weather')
    city_ID = sentence.split()
    city_to_find = city_ID[-1]


 engine.say(forecast)
```

**weather.py**

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.parse
from urllib.parse import  urljoin
from speech import city_to_find


city= city_to_find
weather_page = 'https://weather.com/en-IN/weather/today/l/'
NY ='USNY0996:1:US'


if city == 'New York':
    weather_page+=NY

    #print(weather_page)
    weather = urllib.request.urlopen(weather_page)
    weather_data = BeautifulSoup(weather, 'html.parser')

    temperature = weather_data.find('div', attrs={'class': 'today-daypart-temp'})
    temp = temperature.text.strip() # strip() is used to remove starting and trailing
    weather_condition = weather_data.find('span', attrs={'class': 'today-daypart-wxphrase'})
    update = weather_condition.text.strip() # strip() is used to remove starting and trailing

    forecast = 'Right now in '+city+' it is '+temp+' and '+update
    return forecast
```

I also tried importing the entire files into each other (*i.e import weather and import speech respectively*). But No luck.

Can anyone help me figure out my mistake?

**Note: Both programs are working fine separately**

Comment: as far as I can tell `forecast` is a variable which is dependent on other variables, not a function which is what you want to be importing, also talk about circular dependency, each file is importing something from the other one according to you, that's a big no no

Comment: `speech.py` includes `weather.py`. `weather.py` includes `speech.py`. Then, `speech.py` includes `weather.py`. Okay, the 5th line in the latter includes `speech.py`, which includes `weather.py`, which includes `speech.py`...

Comment: A big mistake is return statement outside of a function!

Comment: All the circular stuff aside, you need to do more than import the file; you must instantiate an object from the imported module to access any variables.  Also, your program could not possibly work with this code.  There are too many errors, like `city_ID = sentence.split()`, which will produce `TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object`

Comment: Even if your pseudocode works for this: `city_to_find = city_ID[-1]
`, it would produce just "York" and your "if ... == "New York" would not evaluate as true.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Comment: It worked. Thank you all for response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

**weather.py**

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.parse
from urllib.parse import  urljoin

def forecast(city_to_find):
    city = city_to_find
    weather_page = 'https://weather.com/en-IN/weather/today/l/'
    NY ='USNY0996:1:US'

    if city == 'New York':
        weather_page+=NY

        #print(weather_page)
        weather = urllib.request.urlopen(weather_page)
        weather_data = BeautifulSoup(weather, 'html.parser')

        temperature = weather_data.find('div', attrs={'class': 'today-daypart-temp'})
        temp = temperature.text.strip() # strip() is used to remove starting and trailing
        weather_condition = weather_data.find('span', attrs={'class': 'today-daypart-wxphrase'})
        update = weather_condition.text.strip() # strip() is used to remove starting and trailing

        forecast = 'Right now in '+city+' it is '+temp+' and '+update
        return forecast
```

And you can call the function

**speech.py**

```
from weather import forecast
engine.say(forecast(city_to_find))
```

I modify the structure, I send the city to the function, not import this data from speech.py to weather.py and the function return the result of the process in speech.py.

Comment: Except one problem. It now prints the output (i.e the forecast) twice. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you added an extra `print` function in some line, the two output are the same exactly ?

Comment: yes it prints them one after other. There is only one print statement.

Comment: Do you can create a pastebin with your code and share?

Answer (score 0):

define a function in weather.py and call it from speech.py

```
forecast = weather.forecast(city_to_find)
```